# Ubuntu 16.04 freezes when using Rstudio (load glyph failed)

Tags: ubuntu, gdb, rstudio

I am using Rstudio (Version 0.99.903) which freezes causing the whole system to freeze ( I am using Ubuntu 16.04); when I start Rstudio after a couple of minutes the whole system freezes.

To try to understand the problem I run this code on the terminal:

```
gdb
file rstudio
run
```

I got this result:

[Debugging Rstudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BljKT.png)

So what does it mean the "`load glyph`"? What should I do to fix this problem?

If I just type :

```
rstudio
```

in the terminal I get this:

> load glyph failed err=6 face=0x199d790, glyph=2797
>
> load glyph failed err=6 face=0x199d790, glyph=2797

Anyone can help? I really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my Ubuntu 16.04. Removing ~/.rstudio* didn't solve the problem, neither nor re-installing RStudio desktop in a plenty of available versions.

However, I switched from Unity to GNOME and I was able to run (but it behaved like a hidden somewhere...) and maximize the RStudio window.

I realised that problem was related with pane layout, which had only 1-2 instead of all 4 windows. This solution https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213238798-Restoring-Missing-Help-Environment-Plot-Panes helped me to restore the pane layout, and everything works fine after logging on Unity again.

Hope it helps.